# How to wear the headphone with less stress for my head?

Tags: headphones

I am using Jabra Evolve 65 **headphones** for my work. However, I find it is quite stressful for my head.

I am looking for some solutions to sort this problem out.
[image]

Comment: Please describe what you find is stressful. There are different aspects to this such as weight, sound reproduction quality - speaking & hearing, proper fitting adjustments, earpiece ventilation, stuff like that.

Comment: Thank Stan, what I feel most uncomfortable is it is too tight even I adjust the maximum length of cover.

Comment: https://www.slashgear.com/sony-wh-1000xm3-review-noise-canceling-headphones-13545212/  You can try similar ones where the ear piece swivels as well.

Answer (score 2):

Well assuming the issue is with the headband, I'd suggest using Headband Cover. This covers the headband with soft padding, so it won't hurt even when tight.

Personally not using any, but from quick look, [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08M5MRZG6) appears to be simple to use: (and quite cheap)

[image: screenshot of product]

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The headband of the earphones is like a spring. Most probably there is a metal band molded inside it to hold its shape and keep it fitted snugly against your ears.

When you pull the earpieces apart [A2] from their original shape [A1], they will return to their original position [A3] due to Hook's Law.

[image: Earphone headband stretch sequences]

Even when you pull the earpieces further apart [B2], they will revert to their original position [B3] so long as the limit of their elasticity has not been exceeded. (That limit is called Young's Modulus.)

You can adjust (reduce) the tension of the headband "spring" PERMANENTLY by pulling apart the earpieces "just" beyond the limit of elasticity as shown in the sequence [C1]…[C2]…[C3].

You can do this *adjustment* in steps, very gradually increasing the stretch [C2] until the headphones fit comfortably [C3].

Good luck.

Comment: You might add to your answer that the reason for decreasing tension is to relive pressure on ears, which is what I find to be the problem with long term wearing. Also, decreasing tension has the minor disadvantage that the headphone tend to fall off your head more easily if you bend over or otherwise don't remain upright.

Comment: @MarkRipley Yes. Thank you for further clarification. I couldn't improve on your comment.